# How to get an array of attributes of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to get an array of attributes of an object using jsx or javascript syntax.

```
state = {
data: [
   { id: 1, name: "DAVE", age: 23, attend: true },
   { id: 2, name: "JHONE", age: 24, attend: true },
   { id: 3, name: "NICK", age: 25, attend: true },
  ],
};
```

**input** => `data`

**output** => `[id,name,age,attend]`

Comment: `Object.keys(data[0])`

Comment: what is the specific problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good Question and very easy answer**

I'm using this in react

```
const headerCount = Object.keys(temp)
console.log(headerCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the data keys as an array using `Object.keys()`

```js
state = {
data: [
   { id: 1, name: "DAVE", age: 23, attend: true },
   { id: 2, name: "JHONE", age: 24, attend: true },
   { id: 3, name: "NICK", age: 25, attend: true },
  ],
};

console.log(Object.keys(state.data[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = state.data.map(el => Object.keys(el))
```

Will give you an array with every key of all the object inside data.

`keys[0]` will give you your requested output.